# How to convert map keys from strings to atoms in Elixir

Tags: elixir

What is the way to convert `%{"foo" => "bar"}` to `%{foo: "bar"}` in Elixir?

Comment: Warning: [`String.to_atom/1`] creates atoms dynamically and atoms are not garbage-collected. Therefore, string should not be an untrusted value, such as input received from a socket or during a web request. Consider using to_existing_atom/1 instead. https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use [Comprehensions](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html):

```elixir
iex(1)> string_key_map = %{"foo" => "bar", "hello" => "world"}
%{"foo" => "bar", "hello" => "world"}

iex(2)> for {key, val} <- string_key_map, into: %{}, do: {String.to_atom(key), val}
%{foo: "bar", hello: "world"}
```

Comment: how to store it into some variable !

Comment: how to convert below into strings of atoms   [%{"foo" => "bar", "hello" => "world"},%{"foo" => "baromater", "hello" => "nope"}]

Comment: Here is a function definition for a recursive helper:

`def keys_to_atoms(string_key_map) when is_map(string_key_map) do
  for {key, val} <- string_key_map, into: %{}, do: {String.to_atom(key), keys_to_atoms(val)}
end`
`def keys_to_atoms(value), do: value`

Comment: (see my answer for a alternate, simple way to do this without using a comprehension)

Comment: Warning! You shouldn't call this on untrusted user input because atom are not garbage collected and could cause you to run into the limit of the number of atoms allowed on the BEAM: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1

Comment: Just note that this does not convert deep/recursive

Comment: Use `String.to_existing_atom()` instead to avoid dynamically creating a large number of atoms until the atom limit is reached, knocking out your elixir applications.

Answer (score 71):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use `Map.new`:

```elixir
%{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
|> Map.new(fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)

%{a: 1, b: 2}
```

Comment: I like this. Because if you are piping, it gets difficult with the for loop.

Comment: Just note that this does not convert deep/recursive

Comment: Also probably better to use `String.to_existing_atom/1` (see docs for [`String.to_existing_atom/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1))

Answer (score 25):

You can use a combination of [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3) and [String.to_atom/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_atom/1)

```elixir
%{"foo" => "bar"}
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {key, val}, acc -> Map.put(acc, String.to_atom(key), val) end)

%{foo: "bar"}
```

However you should be wary of converting to atoms based in user input as they will not be garbage collected which can lead to a memory leak. See [this issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2915#issuecomment-65556180).

You can use [String.to_existing_atom/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#to_existing_atom/1) to prevent this if the atom already exists.

Comment: Yeah I know about memory leak,same thing was in ruby before 2.2 but thank you anyway

Comment: Yes, it was the same thing in Ruby but Elixir is not Ruby and in general this pattern is extremely discouraged in Elixir. The only case I can think it makes sense on top of my mind is when loading data into structs (and then there are safer ways to do it)

Comment: @JoséValim what's the safer way to load data into structs?

Answer (score 14):

Snippet below converts keys of nested json-like map to existing atoms:

```elixir
iex(2)> keys_to_atoms(%{"a" => %{"b" => [%{"c" => "d"}]}})

%{a: %{b: [%{c: "d"}]}}
```

```elixir
  def keys_to_atoms(json) when is_map(json) do
    Map.new(json, &reduce_keys_to_atoms/1)
  end

  def reduce_keys_to_atoms({key, val}) when is_map(val), do: {String.to_existing_atom(key), keys_to_atoms(val)}
  def reduce_keys_to_atoms({key, val}) when is_list(val), do: {String.to_existing_atom(key), Enum.map(val, &keys_to_atoms(&1))}
  def reduce_keys_to_atoms({key, val}), do: {String.to_existing_atom(key), val}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this one is written is the best.

Answer (score 9):

To build on @emaillenin's answer, you can check to see if the keys are already atoms, to avoid the `ArgumentError` that is raised by String.to_atom when it gets a key that is already an atom.

```elixir
for {key, val} <- string_key_map, into: %{} do
  cond do
    is_atom(key) -> {key, val}
    true -> {String.to_atom(key), val}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Jason library.

[michalmuskala/jason](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason)

```elixir
%{
  "key" => "1",
  "array" => [%{"key" => "1"}],
  "inner_map" => %{"another_inner_map" => %{"key" => 100}}
}
|> Jason.encode!()
|> Jason.decode!(keys: :atoms)

%{array: [%{key: "1"}], inner_map: %{another_inner_map: %{key: 100}}, key: "1"}
```

Comment: Very nice. This approach can be modified, from `atoms` to `atoms!`, which switches it to `String.to_existing_atom/1` and avoids leaking atoms. Documentation: https://hexdocs.pm/jason/Jason.html#decode/2

Answer (score 5):

There's a library for this, https://hex.pm/packages/morphix. It also has a recursive function for embedded keys.

Most of the work is done in this function:

```elixir
defp atomog(map) do
  atomkeys = fn {k, v}, acc ->
    Map.put_new(acc, atomize_binary(k), v)
  end

  Enum.reduce(map, %{}, atomkeys)
end

defp atomize_binary(value) do
  if is_binary(value), do: String.to_atom(value), else: value
end
```

Which is called recursively. After reading @Galzer's answer I'll probably convert this to use `String.to_existing_atom` soon.

Comment: How is this recursive? `atomog(%{"a" => %{"b" => 2}})` returns `%{a: %{"b" => 2}}`

Comment: the atomog function is called as part of a recursive function, it is not itself recursive. Check the morphix code itself for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a version of @emaillenin's answer in module form:

```elixir
defmodule App.Utils do
  # Implementation based on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31990445/175830
  def map_keys_to_atoms(map) do
    for {key, val} <- map, into: %{}, do: {String.to_atom(key), val}
  end

  def map_keys_to_strings(map) do
    for {key, val} <- map, into: %{}, do: {Atom.to_string(key), val}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, @Olshansk's answer worked like a charm for me. Thank you for that.

Next, since the initial implementation provided by @Olshansk was lacking support for **list of maps**, below is my code snippet extending that.

```elixir
def keys_to_atoms(string_key_map) when is_map(string_key_map) do
  for {key, val} <- string_key_map, into: %{}, do: {String.to_atom(key), keys_to_atoms(val)}
end

def keys_to_atoms(string_key_list) when is_list(string_key_list) do
  string_key_list
  |> Enum.map(&keys_to_atoms/1)
end

def keys_to_atoms(value), do: value
```

This the sample I used, followed by the output after passing it to the above function - `keys_to_atoms(attrs)`

```elixir
# Input
%{
  "school" => "School of Athens",
  "students" => [
    %{
      "name" => "Plato",
      "subjects" => [%{"name" => "Politics"}, %{"name" => "Virtues"}]
    },
    %{
      "name" => "Aristotle",
      "subjects" => [%{"name" => "Virtues"}, %{"name" => "Metaphysics"}]
    }
  ]
}

# Output
%{
  school: "School of Athens",
  students: [
    %{name: "Plato", subjects: [%{name: "Politics"}, %{name: "Virtues"}]},
    %{name: "Aristotle", subjects: [%{name: "Virtues"}, %{name: "Metaphysics"}]}
  ]
}
```

The explanation for this is very simple. The first method is the heart of everything which is invoked for the input of the type map.
The for loop destructures the attributes in key-value pairs and returns the atom representation of the key.
Next, while returning the value, there are three possibilities again.

1. The value is yet another map.
2. The value is a list of maps.
3. The value is none of the above, it's primitive.

So this time, when the `keys_to_atoms` method is invoked while assigning value, it may invoke one of the three methods based on the type of input.
The methods are organized in the snippet in a similar order.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```elixir
defmodule Service.MiscScripts do
  @doc """
  Changes String Map to Map of Atoms e.g. %{"c"=> "d", "x" => %{"yy" => "zz"}} to
          %{c: "d", x: %{yy: "zz"}}, i.e changes even the nested maps.
  """

  def convert_to_atom_map(map), do: to_atom_map(map)

  defp to_atom_map(map) when is_map(map),
    do: Map.new(map, fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), to_atom_map(v)} end)

  defp to_atom_map(v), do: v
end
```

Comment: Perfect is you're dealing with nested maps (aka recursion)

Answer (score 1):

```elixir
m = %{"key" => "value", "another_key" => "another_value"}
k = Map.keys(m) |> Enum.map(&String.to_atom(&1))
v = Map.values(m)
result = Enum.zip(k, v) |> Enum.into(%{})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use to recursively (1) format map keys as snakecase and (2) convert them to atoms. Keep in mind that you should **never** convert non-whitelisted user data to atoms as they are not garbage collected.

```elixir
defp snake_case_map(map) when is_map(map) do
  Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn {key, value}, result ->
    Map.put(result, String.to_atom(Macro.underscore(key)), snake_case_map(value))
  end)
end

defp snake_case_map(list) when is_list(list), do: Enum.map(list, &snake_case_map/1)
defp snake_case_map(value), do: value
```

Answer (score 1):

I really liked Roman Bedichevskii's answer ... but I needed something that will thoroughly atomize the keys of deeply nested yaml files. This is what I came up with:

```elixir
@doc """
Safe version, will only atomize to an existing key
"""
def atomize_keys(map) when is_map(map), do: Map.new(map, &atomize_keys/1)
def atomize_keys(list) when is_list(list), do: Enum.map(list, &atomize_keys/1)

def atomize_keys({key, val}) when is_binary(key),
  do: atomize_keys({String.to_existing_atom(key), val})

def atomize_keys({key, val}), do: {key, atomize_keys(val)}
def atomize_keys(term), do: term

@doc """
Unsafe version, will atomize all string keys
"""
def unsafe_atomize_keys(map) when is_map(map), do: Map.new(map, &unsafe_atomize_keys/1)
def unsafe_atomize_keys(list) when is_list(list), do: Enum.map(list, &unsafe_atomize_keys/1)

def unsafe_atomize_keys({key, val}) when is_binary(key),
  do: unsafe_atomize_keys({String.to_atom(key), val})

def unsafe_atomize_keys({key, val}), do: {key, unsafe_atomize_keys(val)}
def unsafe_atomize_keys(term), do: term
```

It's main limitation is that if you feed it a tuple {key, value} and the key is a binary, it will atomize it. That is something you want for keyword lists, but it is probably someone's edge case. In any case, YAML and JSON files don't have a concept of a tuple, so for processing those, it won't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [Enum.into/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#into/3) so that I can easily choose between Map, Keyword or any other [Collectable](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Collectable.html)

```elixir
%{"foo" => "bar"}
|> Enum.into(Map.new(), fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)

%{foo: "bar"}
```

```elixir
%{"foo" => "bar"}
|> Enum.into(Keyword.new(), fn {k, v} -> {String.to_atom(k), v} end)

[foo: "bar"]
```

Answer (score 0):

when you have a map inside another map

```elixir
def keys_to_atom(map) do
  Map.new(
    map,
    fn {k, v} ->
      v2 =
        cond do
          is_map(v) -> keys_to_atom(v)
          v in [[nil], nil] -> nil
          is_list(v) -> Enum.map(v, fn o -> keys_to_atom(o) end)
          true -> v
        end

      {String.to_atom("#{k}"), v2}
    end
  )
end
```

**sample:**

```elixir
my_map = %{"a" => "1", "b" => [%{"b1" => "1"}], "c" => %{"d" => "4"}}
```

**result**

```elixir
%{a: "1", b: [%{b1: "1"}], c: %{d: "4"}}
```

**note:** the is_list will fail when you have "b" => [1,2,3] so you can comment/remove this line if this is the case:

```elixir
# is_list(v) -> Enum.map(v, fn o -> keys_to_atom(o) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

We found ourselves doing this a lot in various `Elixir/Phoenix` projects ... 
so we created a tested+documented utility function [`Useful.atomize_map_keys/1`](https://github.com/dwyl/useful#atomize_map_keys1) 
that considers all the answers in this thread.

Install by adding this line to the `deps` your `mix.exs:

```elixir
{:useful, "~> 1.0.8"},
```

Then use:

```elixir
my_map = %{"name" => "Alex", "age": 17}
Useful.atomize_map_keys(my_map)
%{name: "Alex", age: 17}
```

We find this a lot clearer when reading code and allows for pipes e.g:

```elixir
MyApp.fetch_json_data()
|> Jason.decode()
|> Useful.atomize_map_keys()
```

Comment: You can use `|> Jason.decode(keys: &String.to_atom/1)` that will do that for you while decoding (therefore saving memory and processing time)