# Elixir: convert indices to from strings to integer in this Map

Tags: string, dictionary, int, elixir

Can someone please help me figure out a clean way to convert the indices coming in from my front end as a string to an integer? below is the Map in question.

```
%{
  "0" => %{
    "daysOfWeek" => [], 
    "start" => nil, 
    "stop" => nil
  }, 
  "1" => %{
    "daysOfWeek" => [], 
    "start" => nil, 
    "stop" => nil
  }, 
  "2" => %{
    "daysOfWeek" => [], 
    "start" => nil, 
    "stop" => nil
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990134/how-to-convert-map-keys-from-strings-to-atoms-in-elixir#31990445) (replace Atom with Int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `for`, pass the keys through `String.to_integer/1`, and collect into an empty map:

```
iex(2)> map
%{
  "0" => %{"daysOfWeek" => [], "start" => nil, "stop" => nil},
  "1" => %{"daysOfWeek" => [], "start" => nil, "stop" => nil},
  "2" => %{"daysOfWeek" => [], "start" => nil, "stop" => nil}
}
iex(3)> for {k, v} <- map, into: %{}, do: {String.to_integer(k), v}
%{
  0 => %{"daysOfWeek" => [], "start" => nil, "stop" => nil},
  1 => %{"daysOfWeek" => [], "start" => nil, "stop" => nil},
  2 => %{"daysOfWeek" => [], "start" => nil, "stop" => nil}
}
```